# Referring to self during property declaration in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to declare and initialize a property with the following code.

```
class ClassName: UIViewController {

　　private let doneButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style:　UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "doneButtonDidTapped")

   func doneButtonDidTapped() {
      println("Ulala!")
   }
}
```

However, I got the following error.

```
Cannot find an initializer for type 'UIBarButtonItem' that accepts an argument list of type '(title: String, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: ClassName -> () -> ClassName, action: String)'
```

Anybody know what's going on here? Should I give up my attempts to initialize the property inline with the declaration and do the initialization on init() method instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @giorashc says due to swift's 2-phase initialization, self is not yet initalized so you cannot do it.

But I think you could create a lazy inialization:

```
lazy private var doneButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem = {
    [unowned self] in
    return UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style:UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "doneButtonDidTapped")
    }()
```

Comment: Hi Agy, thanks for the code. The [unowned self] thing was new to me!

Comment: Your welcome. It was new to me too just a couple of weeks ago :)

Answer (score 2):

The closure in @agy's answer is unnecessary, you can just do (in Swift 3):

```
lazy var button:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to swift's 2-phase initialization you need to initialize the parent class before you can use `self` in the inheriting class.

In your implementation `self` is yet to be initialized by the parent class so as you said you should move it to the `init` method of your view controller and create the button after calling the parent's initialization method