# Adding a target to a button programmatically throws an error "unrecognized selector sent to class"

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

Not sure why I am getting an "Unrecognized selector sent to class" error when I try to use the button I've created in code.

Here is my code:

```
let sendButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5098039216, green: 0.5215686275, blue: 0.8392156863, alpha: 1)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(postComment), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
```

Comment: Duplicate (though this fact is not obvious) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021390/referring-to-self-during-property-declaration-in-swift

Comment: When posting questions about such an error it is always best to include the complete error message in your question along with pointing out the exact line of code causing the issue.

Comment: Exactly so. You never even told us that `sendButton` was an instance property. If you had, it would have been easy to help you. Without that information, it's basically impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually all a matter of timing. You are declaring an instance property along with a define-and-call function that initializes that property, and you proceed to say `button.addTarget(self...` in that function. The question then is: when will that function's code run? Incredibly, that matters a lot, so much so that it actually changes the meaning of `self`.

When you say `let` to make this declaration, the code runs at a time when the instance does not yet exist. The instance is exactly what we are in the process of forming at that moment; it isn't "cooked" yet. In fact, unbeknownst to you, `self` at that moment means *the UIButton class!* Therefore the resulting target-action is invalid; you have no class method `postComment`; it's an instance method (rightly). And so later on when you tap the button and we try to say `postComment` to the class, we crash. "Unrecognized selector sent to class", exactly as you say.

On the other hand, when you say `lazy var`, the code is not called until after the instance `self` does exist, `self` means the instance, and all is well.

It's terribly confusing to beginners, and to not-so-beginners; even after pointing out the problem, I've proceeded to make exactly the same mistake myself. In my opinion the compiler should catch this and stop you, but it doesn't. I've filed a bug: http://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4865

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Matt. I figured it had to do with the meaning of ‘self’ at a particular time, but I’d never encountered this kind of issue before. Thanks again, cheers.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. As I say, this one has caught me too!

Answer (score 0):

I actually Just figured it out.

For some reason, replacing 'let' with 'lazy var' seems to do the trick. I can't explain why it works, but it does.