# Button in custom UICollectionViewCell class does not taking action

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

Hi I am developing a route finder application, and inside the application when user searches for specific places, app provides number of places on both map and in UICollectionView which contains short description of list of places found and a **"Go" UIButton** to show the direction. However, despite the fact that button is shown on the cell and is touchable, meaning isUserInteractionEnabled is true, button is not triggering an action. "Pressed" is not shown on console. (Note: Screen shot is available for demonstration purposes.)

Declaration of the UICollectionView in MapViewController.

```swift
let collectionViewOfListOfPlaces:UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return cv
    }()
```

In viewDidLoad function of MapViewController this lines are added.

```swift
collectionViewOfListOfPlaces.reloadData()
collectionViewOfListOfPlaces.delegate = self
```

In extension of MapViewController this lines functions are added.

```swift
func setupCollectionViewOfListOfPlaces(){
        hideListViewButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hideListViewButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        collectionViewOfListOfPlaces.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0)
        collectionViewOfListOfPlaces.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: listContentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionViewOfListOfPlaces.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: listContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        collectionViewOfListOfPlaces.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: listContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        collectionViewOfListOfPlaces.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height/5).isActive = true  // ?
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionViewOfListOfPlaces.frame.height/0.8, height: collectionViewOfListOfPlaces.frame.height/1.2)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return landmarks.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionViewOfListOfPlaces.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let cellData = self.landmarks[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = Colors.violet3
        cell.setData(dataa: cellData) //????????
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
```

Custom class:

````swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func didPrintNameOfPlace(placeName: String)
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
//    var data: Landmark? {
//        didSet {
//            guard let data = data else { return }
//
//        }
//    }
    let directButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Go", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        button.addTarget(
            self,
            action: #selector(directButtonPressed),
            for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        return button
    }()
    
    var data: Landmark?
    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        setUpDirectButton()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func setData(dataa: Landmark){
        data = dataa
        
    }
    
    func setUpDirectButton(){
        contentView.addSubview(directButton)
        directButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        directButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        directButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        directButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant:  0).isActive = true
        directButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        directButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        directButton.frame.size.width = 50
        directButton.frame.size.height = 50
    }
    
    @objc func directButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
//        delegate?.didPrintNameOfPlace(placeName: data!.nameOfPlace)
        print("Pressed")
        
    }
}
```[Screen shot link][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/azHSd.jpg
````

Comment: Image is available in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/azHSd.jpg

Comment: please post `cellforItem` method where you used it

Comment: Hi added needed lines of codes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark your button initialise with lazy

```
private lazy var directButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Go", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        button.addTarget(
            self,
            action: #selector(directButtonPressed),
            for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        return button
    }()
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works now, shall I know what was the reason that button was not taking action? Because I am new in Swift, and your explanation would be useful.

Comment: `self` doesn't exist until init has been called. When you add a target to `self` in a let constant, you are defining it before init has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Cut this line:

```
    button.addTarget(
        self,
        action: #selector(directButtonPressed),
        for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
```

...and paste it inside `setupDirectButton`. Your button will start working.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now, shall I know what was the reason that button was not taking action?

Comment: I have explained it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50662472/341994