# Target-Action problems with custom view built from standard views

Tags: swift, macos

I have a custom view subclassing `NSView`, which is just an `NSStackView` containing a label, slider, a second label and a checkbox. The slider and checkbox are both configured to report changes to the view (and eventually, via a delegate to a ViewController):

```
fileprivate extension NSTextField {
    static func label(text: String? = nil) -> NSTextField {
        let label = NSTextField()
        label.isEditable = false
        label.isSelectable = false
        label.isBezeled = false
        label.drawsBackground = false
        label.stringValue = text ?? ""
        return label
    }
}

@IBDesignable
class Adjustable: NSView {

    private let sliderLabel = NSTextField.label()
    private let slider = NSSlider(target: self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)))
    private let valueLabel = NSTextField.label()
    private let enabledCheckbox = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: "Enabled", target: self, action: #selector(enabledChanged(_:)))

    var valueFormatter: (Double)->(String) = { String(format:"%5.2f", $0) }

    ...

    @objc func sliderChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let slider = sender as? NSSlider else { return }

        valueLabel.stringValue = valueFormatter(slider.doubleValue)
        print("Slider now: \(slider.doubleValue)")

        delegate?.adjustable(self, changedValue: slider.doubleValue)
    }

    @objc func enabledChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let checkbox = sender as? NSButton else { return }
        print("Enabled now: \(checkbox.state == .on)")

        delegate?.adjustable(self, changedEnabled: checkbox.state == .on)
    }
}
```

Using InterfaceBuilder, I can add one instance of this to a ViewController by dragging in a `CustomView` and setting it's class in the Identity Inspector. Toggling the checkbox or changing the slider will have the desired effect.

However, if I have multiple instances then in the target-action functions `self` will always refer to the same instance of the view, rather than the one being interacted with. In other words, `self.slider == sender` is only true in `sliderChanged` for one of the sliders. While I can get the correct slider value via `sender`, I cannot update the correct label as `self.valueLabel` is always the label in the first instance of the custom view.

Incidentally, `@IBDesignable` and the code intended to support it have no effect so there's something I'm missing there too - Interface Builder just shows empty space.

The whole file:

```
import Cocoa

fileprivate extension NSTextField {
    static func label(text: String? = nil) -> NSTextField {
        let label = NSTextField()
        label.isEditable = false
        label.isSelectable = false
        label.isBezeled = false
        label.drawsBackground = false
        label.stringValue = text ?? ""
        return label
    }
}

protocol AdjustableDelegate {
    func adjustable(_ adjustable: Adjustable, changedEnabled: Bool)
    func adjustable(_ adjustable: Adjustable, changedValue: Double)
}

@IBDesignable
class Adjustable: NSView {
    var delegate: AdjustableDelegate? = nil

    private let sliderLabel = NSTextField.label()
    private let slider = NSSlider(target: self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)))
    private let valueLabel = NSTextField.label()
    private let enabledCheckbox = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: "Enabled", target: self, action: #selector(enabledChanged(_:)))

    var valueFormatter: (Double)->(String) = { String(format:"%5.2f", $0) }

    @IBInspectable
    var label: String = "" {
        didSet {
            sliderLabel.stringValue = label
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var value: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            slider.doubleValue = value
            valueLabel.stringValue = valueFormatter(value)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var enabled: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            enabledCheckbox.isEnabled = enabled
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var minimum: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            slider.minValue = minimum
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var maximum: Double = 100 {
        didSet {
            slider.maxValue = maximum
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var tickMarks: Int = 0


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        setup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        setup()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        let stack = NSStackView()
        stack.orientation = .horizontal
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        stack.addArrangedSubview(sliderLabel)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(slider)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(valueLabel)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(enabledCheckbox)

        sliderLabel.stringValue = label
        slider.doubleValue = value
        valueLabel.stringValue = valueFormatter(value)
        slider.minValue = minimum
        slider.maxValue = maximum
        slider.numberOfTickMarks = tickMarks

        // Make the slider be the one that expands to fill available space
        slider.setContentHuggingPriority(NSLayoutConstraint.Priority(rawValue: 249), for: .horizontal)

        sliderLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        valueLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

        addSubview(stack)

        stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func sliderChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let slider = sender as? NSSlider else { return }

        valueLabel.stringValue = valueFormatter(slider.doubleValue)
        print("Slider now: \(slider.doubleValue)")

        delegate?.adjustable(self, changedValue: slider.doubleValue)
    }

    @objc func enabledChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let checkbox = sender as? NSButton else { return }
        print("Enabled now: \(checkbox.state == .on)")

        delegate?.adjustable(self, changedEnabled: checkbox.state == .on)
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [Referring to self during property declaration in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021390/referring-to-self-during-property-declaration-in-swift).

Comment: Not related to the issue: `setup` is called twice, from `init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)` and `awakeFromNib()`.

Comment: Changing the two relevant `private let`s to `private lazy var` does indeed fix things.

Comment: Any idea why the `@IBDesignable` might not be working? It calls `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` and the view has a sensible frame in `setup`, but Interface Builder just shows empty space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as described in the question linked by Willeke, was to ensure `init` had completed before referencing `self`. (I'm slightly surprised the compiler allowed it to be used in a property initialiser)

Wrong:

```
private let slider = NSSlider(target: self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)))
private let enabledCheckbox = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: "Enabled", target: self, action: #selector(enabledChanged(_:)))
```

Right:

```
private lazy var slider = NSSlider(target: self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)))
private lazy var enabledCheckbox = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: "Enabled", target: self, action: #selector(enabledChanged(_:)))
```